# Spaces replaced by "?" question mark

Tags: pdfclown

I am use PDFClown 0.1.2 for .NET 4 for stamping PDF in C# console application.
When I Stamping string with spaces (e.g. "Stamped by PDFClown"), using any true type font (Font.Get(pdfdocument, "path\to\font.ttf")), result is incorrect. It view normal in Acrobat Reader, but in other reader (Foxit Reader, Firefox, Debenu PDF Tools) spaces replaced by "?" (e.g. "Stamped?by?PDFClown").

Comment: Maybe these are not real spaces U+20 but for instance a hard space U+A0.

Comment: For example: BlockComposer.ShowText("Stamped by PDFClown"); //C# space is char with code 32

Comment: No idea, what when you search "Stamped by" in Adobe, what when you use a hard-space instead: `"Stamped\u00a0by\u00a0PDFClown"`?

Comment: If I replace 0x20 to 0xa0 in string, space will be normal in Foxit also. If I use 0x20, space will be normal in adobe acrobat and "?" in Foxit.

Comment: Please share a sample output document and probably your pivotal stamping code.

Comment: Example of PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByNvyAQCgZ-HcGZBZVM0UkdoM1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Code fragment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByNvyAQCgZ-HbEtuOGc0SVJSTTQ/view?usp=sharing